# How to skip over failed cards when charging Stripe customers from a Ruby block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I want to create charges in Stripe for a list of of orders in Rails like so:

```
Orders.all.each do |order|
  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :amount   => 100,
    :currency => "usd",
    :customer => order.user.stripe_customer_id
  )
  order.id = charge.id
end
```

But when `Stripe::Charge.create` encounters a failed card, it will throw a `Stripe::CardError: Your card was declined` error and the Ruby block will stop, preventing the rest of the orders from being charged.

Is there a way where I can skip over the orders where the card is declined so the remaining orders can be charged?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

what about using `rescue`?

```
Orders.all.each do |order|
  begin 
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      amount: 100,
      currency: "usd",
      customer: order.user.stripe_customer_id
    )
    order.id = charge.id
  resuce Stripe::CardError => e
    # do something useful with the exception
  end
end
```

This is the short way. You don't want to use exceptions as control flows. 
You want to check what's raising that error and check this with an `if` to prevent that `create` raises an exception

Comment: I try it now. Thanks.

Comment: This is exactly how I have had to handle invalid cards in the past.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was exactly it.  I'll look more into the api now.